# Showing continuity of $f(x,y) = x^y$, for $x\in[0,1]$ and $y\in[a,b]$, where $0<a<b$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

How can we show the continuity of $f(x,y) = x^y$, for $x\in[0,1]$ and $y\in [a,b]$, where $0<a<b$?

Comment: Using what facts?

Comment: The definition of continuity for functions of two variables or anything else that may help

Answer (score 1):

First of all, $f(x,y)=x^y=e^{y\ln x}$. Write $g(x)=e^x$ and $h(x,y)=y\ln x$, so that $f=g\circ h$. Now use the facts that

- a composition of continuous functions is continuous
- a product of continuous functions is continuous
- the functions $(x,y)\mapsto y$ and $(x,y)\mapsto \ln x$ are continuous

Comment: Thank you! Would g(x) need to be g(x,y) here though? Or does having it just as g(x) work?

Comment: Here $g$ is a function of one variable. The maps are $\Bbb R^2\xrightarrow{h} \Bbb R\xrightarrow{g}\Bbb R$. You could pick a different letter than $x$, but it has to only have one input.